# Run python Api in PHP

Tags: php, python, json, bash

I want to exec this python script (Python API).
* I have a form with method POST and a submit button; from this form I ask the user for the country, locality, rfc, etc.
* When the user writes this parameters, and clicks the button, I want to pass this parameters to my script in python and execute it.

This is my php code:

```
<?
$colony = $_POST['colony'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$output = array();
exec("python script.py'".$colony.$country."'",$salida);
echo $salida[0];
?>
```

This is my script.py

```
# encoding=utf-8
import base64
import ssl
import subprocess

from OpenSSL import crypto
import requests


API_PREFIX = 'https://b.listo.mx/api/invoicing'
API_TOKEN = 'Aasdfadsf'
RFC_ID = 6690
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE = '12345678a'


generation_data = [{
    "folio": "415",
    "issued_at": "Mike Van",
    "issued_on": "2016-08-18T03:04:00.000Z",
    "issuer": {
        "colony": sys.argv[1],
        "country": sys.argv[2],
        "email_from": "contacto@ready.mx",
        "email_subject": "Tu factura",
        "employer_num": "WWWW",
        "ext_num": "123",
        "int_num": "234",
        "id": RFC_ID,
        "locality": "",
        "municipio": "Mike",
        "postal_code": "00000",
        "reference": None,
        "rfc": " ",
        "rfc_name": "Services",
        "state": "Mike",
        "street": "Re",
        "tax_regime": "pm"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "description": "Examen IV",
            "quantity": "1.000000",
            "unitary_amount": "123.000000",
            "unitary_amount_with_iva": "142.680000",
            "units": "MX"
        },
        {
            "description": "Certificación I",
            "quantity": "2.000000",
            "unitary_amount": "234.560000",
            "unitary_amount_with_iva": "272.089600",
            "units": "MX"
        }
    ],
    "payment_form": u"Pay",
    "payment_method": "04",
    "payment_method_acct_num": "9876",
    "receiver": {
        "colonia": "P",
        "country": u"M",
        "ext_num": "123",
        "int_num": "456",
        "issuer_rfc": 10,
        "locality": u"M",
        "municipio": "Mike",
        "postal_code": "00000",
        "reference": None,
        "rfc": "TT",
        "rfc_name": "ABC SA de CV",
        "state": u"Mike",
        "street": "Re"
    },
    "series": "A",
    "subtotal": "592.120000",
    "taxes": [
        {"amount": "94.739200", "tax_rate": "16.000000", "tax_type": "IVA", "treatment": "pass_through"}
    ],
    "total": "686.859200"
}]

r = requests.post('https://b.listo.mx/api/invoicing/generate_xml', json=generation_data,
                  headers={'Authorization': 'Token %s' % API_TOKEN}, verify=True)

response = r.json()[0]
xml, original_chain = response['xml'], response['original_chain']

print '-' * 80
print r.json()

# Cargar certificado y llave privada (Firma)
with open('test.cer') as f:
    cert_der = f.read()
    cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert_der))

with open('test.key') as f:
    private_key_der = f.read()

args = ['openssl', 'pkcs8', '-inform', 'DER', '-passin', 'pass:' + PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE]
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
private_pem = proc.communicate(input=private_key_der)[0].strip()
key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, private_pem)

# Timbrado
signature = crypto.sign(key, original_chain, 'sha1')
print "Cadena original = %s" % original_chain
print "Sello = %s" % base64.b64encode(signature)
crypto.verify(cert, signature, original_chain, 'sha1')


certification_data = {
    'xml': xml,
    'certificate_num': ('%0x' % cert.get_serial_number())[1::2],
    'certificate': base64.b64encode(cert_der),
    'signature': base64.b64encode(signature),
    'data': generation_data[0]
}

r = requests.post('%s/certify_xml' % API_PREFIX, json=certification_data,
                  headers={'Authorization': 'Token %s' % API_TOKEN}, verify=False)

#{Aquí me dará el id y el xml tanto url como pdf}
print '-' * 80
print r.json()
```

As you can see, I have tried to get the parameters in python like this:

colony: sys.argv[1],
country: sys.argv[2],

I have some errors with sys.argv[2] (Index undefined) and import requests.

Comment: can you please edit the post and paste the python code into it. Second, what result are you expecting, what result (or error) are you getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems, not the least of which is that you are using unescaped user input in the command line. If someone set `& rm *` as a colony, you could have a problem. [You should look at escaping those.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

The specific problem that you're asking about, however, is caused by the fact that you are passing in both colony and country in a single string `'".$colony.$country."'"` means that Python sees `sys.argv[1]` as the result of combining both of those values into one string. You should use: `'".$colony."' '".$country."'"` instead

Comment: It works fine, but when I try to import requests, I get the same error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0. I need the requests.post to send my json: r = requests.post('https://b.listo.mx/api/invoicing/generate_xml', json=generation_data,
                  headers={'Authorization': 'Token %s' % API_TOKEN}, verify=True)

response = r.json()[0]
xml, original_chain = response['xml'], response['original_chain']